# Video only loads when I move my mouse even though it has autoplay

Tags: html, css, video, slider

Currently on my website I have a video card slider system, but all the videos that overflow from the visible slider will not play even when it gets to the visible part of the slider, and it only starts playing when I move my mouse.

Before I made the slider I already tested that all the videos run normally without the problem, so I'm not sure why the videos won't play even when it gets loaded into the slider since I set autoplay to all of them (I'm pretty sure it should already be loaded even with overflow: hidden).

html:

```
<div class='slider2'>
    <div class='slide-track'>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
        <div class='slide'>
            <video width="450px" height="400px" autoplay muted loop>
                <source src="" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.slider2 {
    height: 450px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.slide-track {
    display: flex;
    width: calc(450px * 14);
    animation: scroll 40s linear infinite;
}

.slide-track:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes scroll {
    0% {
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateX(calc(-450px * 7));
    }
}

.slide {
    height: 400px;
    width: 450px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 30px;
    perspective: 100px;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
    transition: transform 1s;
}

video:hover {
    transform: translateZ(20px);
}

.slider2::before {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, black 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%);
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.slider2::after {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, black 100%);
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 15%;
    z-index: 2;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```